# SSL Certificate with Squarespace as DNS, Heroku as server, and QuotaGuard Static as static IP address provider: CN and Hostname mismatch

Tags: django, ssl, heroku, dns, certificate

Squarespace is saying my SSL certificate is unavailable and Google Search also returns http instead of https, even though my site is able to use https and is flagged as secure by every browser I've tested:

https://www.bencritt.net

This is definitely related to how my website hosting is set up.  My website is hosted on Heroku because it's a Django site and Squareqpace doesn't support hosting for sites developed with that framework.

Heroku, unfortunately, uses dynamic IP addresses.  So, my server's IP address is constantly changing.  This makes setting up A records difficult.  I have to run a third party service called QuotaGuard Static on my Heroku server that provides me with two static IP addresses.  I use these two IP addresses for my A records in my DNS settings in Squarespace.  At some point in the daisy-chain, the SSL is getting obscured and making Squarespace and Google both think I don't have it.

Do you know how I can get both Squarespace and Google Search to recognize my website's SSL?

I've tried adding schema to my website's code that specifies https in an attempt to force Google Search to return the https version of my site in Search results.  I've also used Google Search Console to force additional crawls with this schema in place.  This hasn't worked.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Ben Crittenden",
        "url": "https://www.bencritt.net",
        "sameAs": [
          "https://www.linkedin.com/in/bencritt/",
          "https://github.com/BenCritt",
          "https://stackoverflow.com/users/21613304/ben-crittenden",
          "https://www.bencritt.com",
          "https://www.bencritt.org"
 
        ]
      }
      </script>
```

Comment: Your NS records look like they are messed up.  You have 8 of them pointing to two different DNS hosting companies.  `squarespacedns.com` and  `nsone.net`.   You would normally pick a single DNS hosting company.  Although it looks like you have both providers set up to return identical records (at least for `@` and `www`), so maybe it isn't a problem.

Comment: Why don't you just find a DNS provider that can do `ALIAS`/`ANAME` records for heroku?

Comment: Your website supports http. You should properly redirect to https or just disable http altogether.

Comment: Thank you for helping me so quickly.  This is all great advice.  I'm not sure what's going on with my NS records; thank you for pointing that out.  I also appreciate the idea of disabling http and forcing https.   

I'm thinking I'll have to switch to a domain name service provider that has better support for sites hosted on Heroku.  Then I can get rid of QuotaGuard Static altogether, too.